# TFS merge conflicts, is there any way to find them in a old merge/checkin?

Tags: tfs, merge

Background:
I have run into the problem that half a year later some code is missing.
I have tracked down the culprit to a certain changeset.
Now this changeset contains about 7000 files (after filtering) and that is a tad too much to go through.

Question:
I would like to see a list of all the files in said merge that had a merge conflict and required manual assistance.
Is there a way to retrieve it now or is it gone like tears in rain?

Answer (score 1):

Its gone like tears in the rain... But there is hope.

If you create a branch from the changeset before the merge then re-run the merge you should get the same conflicts.